# Unity2D - On build, the background is shorter than it should be

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 2d

While in editor, everything's working fine, but when I build the game to my phone, the background seems to be short on top and bottom side.

[image]
This is a screenshot from the phone build.

[image]

This is a screenshot from Unity.

I checked all sizes and they were all the same - 800x1280. I think the problem started to happen when I made the cloudy background infinitely move with a quad.
Checked everywhere, can't seem to pin-point the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should resize the background according to screen size. You can do that through code. If you are using `Sprite Renderer`, you can follow this [link](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/create-fullscreen-background-image-in-unity2d-with-spriterenderer) to do so. Here's the main codes needed to resize a `sprite` according to the above link.

```c#
void Awake() {
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    float cameraHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;
    Vector2 cameraSize = new Vector2(Camera.main.aspect * cameraHeight, cameraHeight);
    Vector2 spriteSize = spriteRenderer.sprite.bounds.size;
    Vector2 scale = transform.localScale;
    if (cameraSize.x >= cameraSize.y) { // Landscape (or equal)
        scale *= cameraSize.x / spriteSize.x;
    } else { // Portrait
        scale *= cameraSize.y / spriteSize.y;
    }
}
```

Or if you are using a UI `Panel` under `Canvas` to draw the background, you can set the anchors on the edge points and set the Canvas's `UI Scale Mode` to  `Scale With Screen Size`